# hiding the URL address in the address bar

Tags: php, html

I want to hide the url of the address bar but i have no idea how to do it, i have done some searching but found nothing.
On my website i want people to just see www.roundaboutmk.com on every page, no matter what link/button they click on.
for example, if they click on the "login" button it will take them to the url address www.roundaboutmk.com/login/login.php, i want to hide the "login/login.php"

Is this possible?

Many thanks
connor

Comment: what is the reason to do that?

Comment: Add more style to your life: [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)

Comment: @theHack: Think "admin interfaces".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it.
It seems you are under the impression of some sort of delusion.
While there are not a single reason to do that and whole lot of reasons to keep the url.
The url is not just for decoration, you know. It's on purpose.

Think your case over and then ask another question.

Comment: thank you for your comment, and i think i'm not going to do it anymore, thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: The "You don't need it" looks like a guess. I think you don't need to press your needs onto others. However it's fine to tell that users might live in an illusion, as one could assume if it's imaginable for the author of the answer, he is clever enough to proclaim this for his own.

Comment: @hakre 1. It is not a guess, I happen to live long enough to get acquainted with all the noob delusions. 2. There is a problem. Let's say there are 2 solutions for the task: a right one and perverted one. Try to get to the noob's pace - both looks *equal* to him. He has no experience to judge. So, he judges by some weird criterias. And your "as one could assume if it's imaginable " wouldn't convince anyone. There is a shitload ansers in SO with wrong answers accepted, just because others do *suggest*, not *insist.*

Comment: I actually need to do this too. I have to put something online for my boss tomorrow, but he does not have access to the ftp. So i have to put it on my private website which has a awkward domain name and needs a longer path.

Comment: @Your common sense...May be there are not a single reason to do that, in my view nothing wrong in connor's question.

Answer (score 6):

1. simplest: put your site into a frameset.
2. simple: put your site into an iframe styled to fill the entire browser window.
3. not so simple: recode your site to use ajax

1 is deprecated in HTML5, but still works

2 works

3 wouldn't recommend it

apart from the technical things... I wouldn't recommend doing this anyway. It's not userfriendly.

Comment: It's funny to receive downvotes on a useful answer just because someone thinks that the question shouldn't be answered. I mean, hiding the address bar COULD be justified, maybe he wanted to code some sort of online game or some sort of antropo-/socio-logical experiment demonstrating the catastrophic consequences of a masked URL.

Comment: Yes, actually it is very useful when you design administration interfaces for web applications or sites.  In these cases many times you don't want or need people to know or to link to the specific urls, you want to force them to use the interfaces only. Then it makes perfect sense to hide the urls in the address bar.

Answer (score 4):

Make all links load their content using AJAX and replace the content of the current page, the problem is "you'll look realy bad in google eyes" if you don't atleast put a hash in the url.

Comment: thanks for the down vote, it doesn't realy answers his question does it ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not considered good style because nobody will be able to link to a specific piece of content on your site.

BUT: you can use a frameset with 100% like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <frameset rows="100%">
      <frame src="index.html" name="Your Title" />
    </frameset>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: true, after reading all the comments that every one has made, im thinking about not doing it, before i asked the question i could not think of any reason not to do it, but i think im just going to leave it how it is :), thank you for your comment

Answer (score -1):

Not if you use the iframe where actual page processing is done, or all content is loaded via ajax requests.

Comment: thank you for responding so quickly, so your saying if i use ajax to go from one page to another it will seem that i am still on the same page, (i have never used ajax before)

Answer (score -1):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]

save the file
.htaccess

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why and how you code would solve the OP's problem

Answer (score -2):

Looks like there's no real answer on here. Let me provide an actual answer. Instead of going to each individual pages when you click on links, ect, you can just include every files on index depending on the POST name of the last link clicked.

For example, if an user click on a link going to login.php, set the action to index.php, and but set the POST value to login.php. Then when it goes to index.php, get the POST value. If the POST value is 'login.php', then include the file login.php. Same thing for all the other files. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that while this hides the links you have, those pages can still be accessed if you type them in the address bar.